# Segmentation Fault Lista Encadeada em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando criar uma lista simplesmente encadeada em C, o objetivo é pegar um struct de alunos inserir e listar, porém o me codigo está dando falha de segmentação e nao sei o motivo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Aluno TAluno;

struct Aluno
{
  int matricula;
  char nome[40];
  float media;
  struct Aluno *proximo;
};

void inserir(TAluno **cabeca);
void listar(TAluno *cabeca);

int main()
{
  TAluno *cabeca = NULL;
  TAluno *noatual;
  char q;

  do
  {
    printf("\n\nOpcoes: \nI -> para inserir novo aluno;\nL -> para listar os alunos;\nS -> para sair \n:");
    scanf("%c", &q); // Le a opção do usuario
    switch (q)
    {
    case 'i':
    case 'I':
      inserir(cabeca);
      break;
    case 'l':
    case 'L':
      listar(cabeca);
      break;
    case 's':
    case 'S':
      break;
    default:
      printf("\n\n Opcao nao valida");
    }
    fflush(stdin); // limpa o buffer de entrada
  } while ((q != 's') && (q != 'S'));

  // Desaloca a memoria alocada para os elementos da lista

  noatual = cabeca;
  while (noatual != NULL)
  {
    cabeca = noatual->proximo;
    free(noatual);
    noatual = cabeca;
  }
}

// Lista todos os elemetos na lista

void listar(TAluno *noatual)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (noatual != NULL) // Enquanto nao chega no fim da lista
  {
    i++;
    printf("\n\nAluno numero %d\nMatricula: %d \nNome: %s \nMedia: %f", i, noatual->matricula, noatual->nome, noatual->media);
    noatual = noatual->proximo; // Faz noatual apontar para o proximo
  }
}

void inserir(TAluno **cabeca)
{
  TAluno *noatual, *nonovo;
  int matricula;
  char nome[40];
  float media;
  printf("\n Matricula do novo aluno: ");
  scanf("%d", &matricula);
  printf("\n Nome do aluno: ");
  scanf("%s", nome);
  printf("\n Media do aluno: ");
  scanf("%f", &media);

  if (*cabeca == NULL) // Se ainda nao existe nenhum aluno na lista
  {
    // Cria um
    *cabeca = (TAluno *)malloc(sizeof(TAluno));
    (*cabeca)->matricula = matricula;
    strcpy((*cabeca)->nome, nome);
    (*cabeca)->media = media;
    (*cabeca)->proximo = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    // Se ja existem elementos na lista, deve percorrer ate o seu final e inserir o novo elemento
    noatual = *cabeca;
    while (noatual->proximo != NULL)
      noatual = noatual->proximo;
    nonovo->matricula = matricula;
    strcpy(nonovo->nome, nome);
    nonovo->media = media;
    nonovo->proximo = NULL;
    noatual->proximo = nonovo; // Faz o ultimo apontar para o novo
  }
}
```

Comment: Vai ser mais fácil de ajudar se você informar onde está ocorrendo a segmentation fault. Edite o título da sua pergunta para que seja mais relacionado ao problema que você está enfrentando também.

Comment: aparentemente esta no apontamento da void inserir().. Estou testando algumas mudanças mais ate agr nd

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a função `inserir` pede um argumento do tipo ponteiro para ponteiro para `TAluno` e nesse `switch` dentro da `main` você está passando um simples ponteiro para `TAluno`. A solução para o problema é passar o endereço de `cabeca` como argumento.

Trecho original defeituoso:

```
case 'i':
    case 'I':
      inserir(cabeca);
      break;
```

Trecho retificado:

```
case 'i':
    case 'I':
      inserir(&cabeca);
      break;
```